# Angular TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I came across something a bit strange in an app I inherited from a friend. I noticed that in the console I am getting the following error when the user clicks a button to download a file (which is generated using dynamic data from an api call).

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')
```

I noticed something strange or unfamiliar to me. The click event method in my Angular component looks like so:

```
downloadCertificate(): void {
    this.downloadService.generateCertificate(
      () => {
        if (this.user?.validUser) { // this is always true
          this.userApi.getCert(this.user?.id); // this returns an observable from an api http call
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

when looking into the `downloadService` and inspecting the `generateCertificate` method, I find the following (I have removed a lot of code for readability)

```
generateCertificate(apiCall: Function): void {
    console.log(apiCall()); // this outputs Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
    (<Observable<any>>apiCall()).subscribe(
      (resp:any) => {
        // do something
      },
      () => {
       // do something in error       
      }
    );
  }
```

So it seems that a function is passed as an argument, when executed this calls an api and we subscribe to the returned value. Okay,  I have never really seen code like this or this way of passing a function, but anyway it outputs the error in the console that it cannot subscribe to what is returned. Hence the error. I thought that an Observable wasn't being returned but when I execute the passed function in a `console.log` statement the following is returned

```
Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

I am confused as what is being returned from the passed argument is returning an observable and I should be able to subscribe. What am I doing wrong here?

I realize this maybe a little confusing and I have tried to simplify the problem. If my wording is bad or I am not making sense please say so and I shall rework my question. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The only thing in my mind is there is 2+ calls to the `generateCertificate`, one is valid with  `apiCall` that actually returns an observable and which is logged in console, and one is your actual code which is not returning anything. In your code you need to add a `return` before this.userApi.getCert (asuming it actually returns an observable) and to return something aside for `else` due to you will get a runtime error if `if (this.user?.validUser)` will be false.

Comment: I noticed in testing that sometimes nothing was being returned from this.userApi.getCert

Answer (score 0):

Your getCert calls return payload is lost as you don't assign it to anything or return it.

```
downloadCertificate(): void {
    this.downloadService.generateCertificate(
      () => {
        if (this.user?.validUser) { // this is always true
          this.userApi.getCert(this.user?.id); // You need a return statement here
        }
      }
    );
  }
```